# Battlefield 1 vehicle position icons

Tags: battlefield-1

What does the X with grey background mean on the vehicle positions graphic?

Orange is your current position, and green is squad mates. I used to think it marked the next position you'd move to when pressing the button to change seats, but this seems to have changed with the latest update.

[image: Icon]

As you can see above, I am currently in position 4, my squad mate is in position 2, position 1 marks a non-squad team mate, and position 3 is marked with the icon. If there were more seats available, only one would have the X symbol. I remember first getting the game and the X would denote where I would move to next (when pressing X on PS4 version conveniently). However, since the latest update this behaviour has changed so my assumption is either wrong, or the patch has broken stuff.

Does anyone know what the X is telling me?

Comment: can you throw a picture in your question please?  also, what system are you playing for?  X for XBox is different from PS, could mean different things per system

Comment: I'm still thinking that's where you move to.  IF, by some chance you didn't move there, did someone else move at the same time and you got their previous seat instead?  Might be something to think about

Comment: oh, and what has changed?  what's the functionality when you do hit "X" if it's not the same as before?

Comment: It seems like the X and your next position is always out of sync now (unless it happens to be the only seat left).

Comment: Is there a delay but you go to that seat? Or you just don't go at all?

Comment: No, you end up in a different seat.

Comment: I looked here: http://answers.ea.com/t5/Bug-Reports/bd-p/battlefield-1-bug-reports-en  and got nothing.  I'm checking another official bug/issue site to see if it's there.

Comment: This is the other site: https://forums.battlefield.com/en-us/categories/Battlefield-1-Bugs-%26-Issues  This one is the official, straight to the devs bugs and issues.  I would recommend that you log in, and create a forum for it.  You probably aren't the only one that's having this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does the X with grey background mean on the vehicle positions
>   graphic?

The X marks the next position the player will move to.

There appeared to be a bug that is fixed after the [Winter Update](https://www.battlefield.com/news/update-notes) (February 2017), although mention of the fix isn't present in the release notes. The bug is certainly present on the Playstation 4 version before the update.

Post update, there appears to be another bug where the X isn't displayed at all in certain circumstances.